# VB.NET serialization error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, serialization, binary-serialization

I'm trying to serialize the main class in my VB solution. I've added the Serializable attribute at the top of my class like so:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class Form1
```

and I'm using the following code to serialize:

```
Public Sub serializeThis()
    Dim fStream As FileStream
    Try
        fStream = New FileStream("C:\ObjectData.bin", FileMode.Create)
        Dim bfmtr As New BinaryFormatter
        bfmtr.Serialize(fStream, Me)
        fStream.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to serialize: " & ex.Message)
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I call this method I'm getting the error:

> Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' in Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   is not marked as serializable.

I'm guessing this is because you can't serialize the form that is attached to the class or something, but I really don't know what I'm doing.

Can I serialize all of the objects contained in my Form1 class somehow, without getting this error? I don't want to store any data about the form controls, I just need to save all the objects that I've defined at the top of the `Form1` class.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Form` is not serializable, you cannot serialize the form itself. (The form is not *attached* to your `Form1` class. Your `Form1` class *is* the form, since it derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.)

What you can do, however, is to serialize just the objects you want to serialize:

```
Public Sub SerializeThis()
    Dim fStream As FileStream
    Try
        fStream = New FileStream("C:\ObjectData.bin", FileMode.Create)
        Dim bfmtr As New BinaryFormatter()

        bfmtr.Serialize(fStream, object1)
        bfmtr.Serialize(fStream, object2)
        bfmtr.Serialize(fStream, object3)
        ' ...

        fStream.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to serialize: " & ex.Message)
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

There are two things to watch out for:

- The classes of all the objects you want to serialize (object1, object2, ...) must be marked as `<Serializable()>`. You can check this in the documentation (Example: [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) is marked as serializable).
- Be sure to *deserialize* the objects in the same order.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the error. The problem is that I've got quite a large number of these objects in the Form1 class (all serializable as far as I know) and I was hoping to avoid explicitly serializing each one. If I move the objects I want to persist to a separate class, would that work? Otherwise, can you possibly explain why I need to deserialize in the same order? Cheers

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, putting them in a separate class should work. You need to mark this class as `<Serializable()>`. It's good practice to separate user interface (Form1) and data (your new class) anyway.

Comment: @Andrew: You need to deserialize them in the same order, because your file stream will contain `bytesForObject1 bytesForObject2 ...`, and reconstructing an object2 out of `bytesForObject1` won't work. ;-)